# script to send out all attachment in a folder one by one

Tags: javascript, email, batch-file, email-attachments

I have tried to use batch script to send out email with a specify attachment.

I have got a critical task.

It requires me to send out all the attachments within the folder **one by one**.

The **number** of file in a folder is **dynamic**.

How can I achieve this goal with scripting? It is not restricted by any language.

Is there any example that I can learn from?

Thank you so much. Many Thanks!!!

Comment: If you have Outlook installed, use VBA instead of batch; it's actually designed for this sort of thing.

Answer (score 0):

The below example shows use of the "mailsend.exe" tool which you must acquire ([mailsend](https://github.com/muquit/mailsend)).  The example sends a separate email for all files matching attach*.*  in the current directory via gmail -- adjust as required.  You must supply proper gmail credentials.

```
@echo off& setlocal
set sc=mailsend -smtp smtp.gmail.com -t toaddr@todomain.com
set sc=%sc% -port 587 -starttls -auth -f yourgmailaddr@gmail.com
set sc=%sc% -user yourgmailaddr@gmail.com -pass yourgmailpw
for %%f in (attach*.*) do %sc% -attach %%f,bin,a
```